# Temp Data to use for filtering purpose

Tags: sql

I don't have access to insert data to database, but I can retrieve the data from the data base using the Sql query. And I cannot use large data set in Sql code, instead I need to take csv file values as look up value. How do I do it?

Comment: Need more details.  Please also tag with database platform.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe use a temp table

```
SELECT id, name, age
INTO #tmp_old_students
FROM student
WHERE age > 60
```